# Deleting last item from spinner deletes the entire list

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to use a spinner control that will enable the user to delete any list element. 
I have an 'add' button to add elements to the list, and a 'delete' button that removes the currently-displayed item from the list.

It works as expected **except** when the user deletes the last item in the list. At that point, all of the list's items are deleted.

My code is as follows:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // grab our UI elements so we can manipulate them (for the Spinner)
    // or add listeners to them (in the case of the buttons)
    m_myDynamicSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.dynamicSpinner);
    m_addItemText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newSpinnerItemText);
    Button addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AddBtn);
    Button clearButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ClearBtn);

    // create an arrayAdapter an assign it to the spinner
    m_adapterForSpinner = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ((ArrayAdapter)m_adapterForSpinner).setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    m_myDynamicSpinner.setAdapter(m_adapterForSpinner);

    // add listener for addButton
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addNewSpinnerItem();
        }
    });

    clearButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clearSpinnerItems();
        }
    });
}

// add listener for addButton
private void addNewSpinnerItem() {
    if (m_addItemText.getText().length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The textView is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        CharSequence textHolder = "" + m_addItemText.getText();
        ((ArrayAdapter) m_adapterForSpinner).add(textHolder);
    }
    m_addItemText.setText("");
}

private void clearSpinnerItems() {
    m_myDynamicSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            Object t = m_adapterForSpinner.getItem(pos);
            ((ArrayAdapter) m_adapterForSpinner).remove((CharSequence) t);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO
        }
    });
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: Do you have a setSingleChoiceItems or setMultiChoiceItems in spinner?and ,can you plz provide some code so that we might help you in better way

Comment: what response do you get in Log.v("Item removed", t + "");
  ?

Comment: by using Log.v("Item removed", t + ""); i get the selected item but i am unable to delete the selected item.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is that the deletion is inside the onItemSelected callback, which gets called every time you are deleting an entry, thus deleting recursively until you effectively do not have any more entries to select. If you add a log inside that method:

```
Log.d("Spinner", "Count: " + m_adapterForSpinner.getCount());
```

you will see what I mean. I'm sure you can come up with more elegant code, but a quick and dirty hack is to set up a boolean flag to stop the recursion after the first deletion. See the snippet below and add the commented lines to your own code:

```
public class SpinnerTest extends Activity {
    Spinner m_myDynamicSpinner;
    EditText m_addItemText;
    ArrayAdapter m_adapterForSpinner;

    public static boolean cleared = false;  //   <--- set up a static boolean here

       @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// all your code unchanged

        clearButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                cleared=false;   //   <--- nope, we did not clear the value yet

                clearSpinnerItems();
            }
        });
    }

// code unchanged

    private void clearSpinnerItems() {
        m_myDynamicSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                Object t = m_adapterForSpinner.getItem(pos);
                Log.d("Spinner", "Count: " + m_adapterForSpinner.getCount());

                if (!cleared)  //   <--- did I do it already?

                    ((ArrayAdapter) m_adapterForSpinner).remove((CharSequence) t);

                Log.d("Spinner", "Count: " + m_adapterForSpinner.getCount());

                cleared=true;  // I did it!

            }

// code unchanged
```

Comment: this is right, after removing a item the Spinner select a new one and called himself until no item left. Xou shoud not register a onitemselect Listener but select the item you want to delete and delete it by clicking the Button

Comment: @2red13 yes, that's what I would do also, but I am assuming this is a test case for a code I did not see, so I am giving the solution that changes the structure the least. In fact, this approach has a second problem: you cannot delete the option that is already selected (since it does not fire onItemSelected).

Comment: @Shrey I'm glad it worked for you. Just make sure that the notice also the problem I mention in my comment to 2red13 above.

Comment: @Aleadam : can't this code work on list view to delete item on delete button click ???

Answer (score 1):

i cann't understand your question.any way you can get the position of the selected item by using getSelectedItemPosition() method.

Comment: m using android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item

Comment: and android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item

Comment: @shruti...just try the following code in clearspinneritem     m_myDynamicSpinner.removeViewAt(    m_myDynamicSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()); and put the listener code out of the method.